# Deleting number from text box produces error

Tags: c#, textbox, unhandled-exception

I have a `TextBox` in which I wanna place a number, the program is supposed to read it, by converting it into a decimal, however, after performing the needed maths with the number, if I delete it from the `TextBox`, it immediatly produces an error:

> Format exception was unhandled ( input string in a incorrect format)

this happens on the line on which I try to convert the text into a decimal

```
private void readW_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string _W = readW.Text;
    _Wd = Convert.ToDecimal(_W);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get

> Format exception was unhandled ( input string in a incorrect format)

because `string.Empty` cannot be converted to a `decimal`.

You can use [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to inform you if parsing fails:

```
bool success = decimal.TryParse(_W, out _Wd);
if (success) {
    // Use the result
}
else {
    // Depending on your needs, do nothing or show an error
}
```

Note that `_W` being `string.Empty` may be a condition you want to ignore, while other parse failures might warrant an error message.  If so, your `else` might look like

```
else {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_W)) ShowAnErrorMessageSomehow();
}
```

Comment: Using the result means "_Wd = Convert.ToDecimal(_W);", if it becomes a empty box, the program will do nothing, instead of providing an error, is this correct?

Comment: Use `decimal.TryParse` *instead of* `Convert.ToDecimal()`.  `decimal.`TryParse()` returns *false* if parsing fails, whereas `Convert.ToDecimal()` throws an Exception.  For ordinary program flow control (e.g. user enters no text), it is preferable to check a boolean result than to catch an exception. In the code I have shown, `Wd` will contain the parsed decimal value if `success` is *true*.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're making it so the number can't be converted into a decimal. Unsurprisingly, this causes the conversion to fail. Try using `Decimal.TryParse` instead:

```
private void readW_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string _W = readW.Text;
    Decimal.TryParse(_W, out _Wd);
}
```

This will prevent the exception if the conversion fails. It will also return a bool, which you can use to perform other operations conditionally only when the conversion succeeds, e.g.:

```
private void readW_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string _W = readW.Text;
    if(Decimal.TryParse(_W, out _Wd))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Valid decimal entered!");
    } 
}
```

Comment: But when i use " Decimal.TryParse(_W, out _Wd); " it will convert the text into decimal just as the previous code, only with the added function of TryParse, is this correct?

Comment: @CésarAmorim You don't need to use `Convert.ToDecimal` at all - TryParse does the same conversion as `Convert.ToDecimal`, except that it won't throw `FormatExceptions` and the return value is a `bool` telling you whether or not the conversion was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. But make sure that user can type only numbers in the textbox. Thanks.

```
private void readW_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string _W = readW.Text;
    _Wd = Convert.ToDecimal("0"+_W);
}
```